# BottlePy only shows 127.0.0.1 when I use NGINX

Tags: nginx, bottle

I'm using bottlepy @port 80, now I have installed NGINX, and configure with this options:

```
        (...)
        listen       443 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate    /xxx/xxx/xxx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /xxx/xxx/xxx.key;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
                proxy_set_header       Host            $proxy_host;
                #proxy_set_header        Host            $REMOTE_ADDR;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        (...)
```

But in Bottle LOG, now all requests are from 127.0.0.1.

Example:

```
May 25 18:11:02 servername processd: 127.0.0.1 - - [2016-05-25 18:11:02] "GET /info HTTP/1.0" 200 187 0.007680
```

Please can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')